# Do we want to lower the close vote threshold?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, voting-to-close

Stack Overflow [now has a 3 close vote threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good)

> We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold on Stack Overflow from 5 to 3.

Shog9 then made [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good#comment743117_391832)

> Other sites can have [whatever threshold is most appropriate for them](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/cancelling-election-lets-try-something-else-testing-three-vote-question-clos)

So, do we want to request lowering our threshold to three?

Vote up for agree, and down for disagree. Add an answer if you have some longer thoughts.

After a while, we can look at the vote spread, and if it looks positive enough, I will take the lead of getting in contact with the CM team for next steps.

Comment: Shamelessly nearly a copy/paste of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341810/160923

Comment: Will this automatically lower the reopen threshold as well?

Comment: @leymannx Yes, the number of re-open votes would be lowered as well.

Comment: OK, we have 6/0 on the question votes.  I think that is pretty much consensus, given the number of people that participate on MDA.  Sending a msg to the CM team.

Comment: The CM team has this in the queue.

Answer (score 5):

As a diamond moderator, I would like to see the threshold lowered. I do not like closing questions outright; I think some community consensus is needed so that diamond moderator bias doesn't creep in.  Right now, the site doesn't get enough traffic to warrant the current five vote threshold.

And, remember that [closure doesn't not always mean the end of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question).

Comment: Totally agree, I'd like to see it lowered too

Comment: I agree too, but on the basis that there are more users asking questions than users who can/do vote to close questions.

Answer (score 3):

Some of you may have noticed the Meta Stack Exchange post - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (it's linked in the featured on meta sidebar) - we've finally got this project under way and Drupal is one of the sites we'll be running the test on.

Starting tomorrow, I'll be changing the site setting and closing and reopening will require only three votes. This test will run for 45 days and will be turned back to five votes to close and reopen while I review the data from the 13 sites. After we've seen the impact, I'll be posting results and, if there aren't negative impacts, we will change the setting to three permanently.

A few weeks into this, I'll be posting a question here on meta to ask for your thoughts about this change, so you will have an opportunity to discuss the impact.

Thank you so much for your patience while we got this prioritized and scheduled. There's a lot more information in the MSE post, so please review it.

Comment: Does it make sense, for the moderators, to stop closing questions that don't have 2 closing votes, for the next 45 days?

Comment: I wouldn't say *stop* outright. If y'all typically close stuff as soon as it comes up, you might want to hold back a bit and see how the community manages. I don't want this test to end up with an influx of low quality content on your site! I'm personally a big fan of using the 10k tool for closing to find questions that are close to being closed. If one of the reasons y'all are doing the bulk of the work is that no one is *flagging* or casting that first vote to close, that's something that we're concerned about, too.

Comment: Cool! It finally makes sense again to go through the review queues. 